# JMeter - HTTPS proxy recorder - Cannot find keytool application and no keystore was provided

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am struggling with this error to record a scenario using JMeter 5.1.1. When the start button is clicked, the pop message suggests an error and checking it further in logs, receive an error "could not initialize key store"

[image]

To resolve this, I provided the below setting in system.properties file but it did not work

> keytool.directory=C:\Program
> Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3\bin

Further, setting Java_Home and Path in Jmeter.bat file also did not help

> SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3
> SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

```
2020-10-05 21:08:45,453 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store
java.io.IOException: Cannot find keytool application and no keystore was provided**
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1494) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:540) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:592) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using apache 5.1 and upgrading to a latest version 5.3 resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Using spaces JDK location is not the best idea](https://superuser.com/questions/119610/spaces-and-parenthesis-in-windows-path-variable-screws-up-batch-files) however if this is something you cannot control you can surround the JDK location with quotation marks like:

```
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3 SET"
```

More information: [Using Spaces in File Names](http://help.seagullscientific.com/10.1/en/Content/file_command_params_longfilenames.htm)

There is also alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](http://help.seagullscientific.com/10.1/en/Content/file_command_params_longfilenames.htm), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, keystores, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response but even after removing the spaces, I still get the same error. the new settings look like 
`SET JAVA_HOME=C:\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3
SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

if not defined JM_LAUNCH (
    set JM_LAUNCH=java.exe
)

if exist jmeter.bat goto winNT1
if not defined JMETER_BIN (
    set JMETER_BIN=%~dp0
)
`

Comment: I was only using chrome extension earlier to record the scenarios which were quick and easy. However, due to project's decision, it was recommended to use only JMeter proxy recording. 
If you would like to see the files JMeter.bat, User.properties and System.properties these are available on this link.[JMeterFilesLink](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xH7iBZ4uiXbGhTJeyvRoMdDdA706UlIk?usp=sharing)

Comment: I fail to see that you removed spaces

Comment: Forgive my ignorance if I fail to understand, the only space it had was in "Program Files" while setting up JAVA_HOME. Which has been removed now.
`SET JAVA_HOME=C:\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3`
`SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
if you see any other issue, kindly suggest